# Replace all non latin characters with their latin a-z counterparts and word count in VBA

Tags: vba, alphanumeric, word-count, non-latin

I am trying to write a script in VBA that
   will:

- replace all É and other similar
  characters with their latin
  counterparts.
- Remove all non alpha numeric
  characters.
- Remove duplicate spacing
- then word count the string

I have worked out that i can split the string on " " and count the elements to get the word count... but I am struggling on the rest of it. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Word has a word count built in for sentences, paragraphs and the entire document:

```
 ActiveDocument.Words.Count
```

As for replace, it is probably easiest to record a macro to see how this works. You will have to replace the accented characters one by one, or use RegEx to replace all **A** type (Å, Ä, Â    ,Á, À) characters with **A**, and so on.